# Bootstrap React Component Fails to Load

Tags: reactjs

**I've created a react component called ImagePost and when I call it in my App.js it doesn't return on page load.**

```
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';
import Row from 'react-bootstrap/Row';
import Col from 'react-bootstrap/Col';

const ImagePost = () => {
  return (
      <div className='container'>
        <Container fluid='md'>
            <Col xs={6}><img src={'./Images/lonepeak.jpg'} alt="Post Image"></img></Col>
            <Row>
                <Col>Title</Col>
                <Col>Description</Col>
            </Row>
        </Container>
      </div>
  )
}

export default ImagePost
```

Answer (score 0):

Pls, check you imported the function at the top of app.js and that paths are correctly done.
If it is inside the route check the routing path. It works finely in my local(attached img at the bottom).

in app.js:

```
import ImagePost from "./ImagePost/ImagePost";
...
 <Route path="/imagePost" element={<ImagePost></ImagePost>} />
```

```
package.json:
"react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-activity": "^2.1.3",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.5.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-bootstrap": "^0.26.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
```

[image]

Comment: My path seems correct, in fact if I remove the bootstrap elements (<Container><Row><Col>) my app loads everything correctly.

Comment: Then maybe the problem is in react-bootstrap. Pls, check it is installed correctly and at the root of the app. I got no error using React Bootstrap using the above code. I attached my package.json.

Comment: Looking into this all now, thank you!